# What is the connection with James Woods?

Tags: family-guy

James Woods is a prominent artifact in Family Guy; James Woods High School, the many episodes with his character and the different story lines with James Woods and characters throughout Quohog.

What is the connection with James Woods and the show?

Comment: They do a lot of random stuff that only the show creators find funny.  That's why South Park hates them so much.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From what I've been able to piece together is this all started with Seth MacFarlane deciding to name the High School, in the show, "James Woods High". Primarily, because Seth MacFarlane is from Rhode Island, and James Woods is the first famous person also from Rhode Island that came to mind when deciding on a name. It was also a running joke to name the woods near Quoahog "James Woods".

> Woods is among only a handful of famous people from the tiny state of Rhode Island where Family Guy is set.
>
> -From [Yahoo Answers](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090617081611AAuRpqU) asking the same question.

After a number of episodes James Woods himself got wind of his name being used in the show, thought it was hilarious, and contacted Seth to make an appearance on the show. Seth then got to work writing a show around James Woods.

> James Woods is playing himself. The school on the show is called James Woods High, and he got wind of that and thought it was funny and wanted to do the show. We were obviously thrilled, so we wrote an episode around him.
>
> -[AV Club Seth MacFarlane Interview](http://www.avclub.com/article/seth-macfarlane-13910)

The episode with James Woods had good viewership and they liked working with James Woods, so he became a reoccurring character.

> 7.7 on [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0576958/)

Comment: Not sure what I was expecting. I believe this is the correct answer, but it isn't satisfying. Guess I was expecting something ridiculous?

Comment: @DustinDavis Like what? James Woods stealing MacFarlane's identity and family? :)

Comment: Can we really use Yahoo Answers as a source?

Comment: @Mario That would make a great Episode of Family Guy! Heh